# Difference between using find_packages() vs "requirements.txt" for setup.py script

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging

I've been working on packaging a python project to so I can install it on other systems in a lab. In my research on how to go about creating the setup.py script, I've seen two methods.

1) use "pip freeze > requirements.txt" command; then "packages='requirements.txt'" in the setup script

2) Simply using "packages=find_packages()" in the setup script

My question is, what is the difference between these two methods?  It seems like "find_packages" does the same as "pip freeze" but does nothing in terms of installing a modules where there are none to begin with.

Can anyone explain how these two methods differ, or just explain what each one is doing so I can make a more informed decision on which method to use?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, I suggest you consult https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/ for all your Python packaging research.

Comment: "It seems like "find_packages" does the same as "pip freeze"" — What makes you think that?  They do completely orthogonal things.

Comment: I say it "seems" to be the same judging by what I've read, which is why I don't think I understand it correctly.  How I understand it, "pip freeze" creates an "image" of all modules used in a project and puts them in a list that can later be used on install.  "Find_packages" (again, how I understand it) looks for all modules in a project with an "__init__" file and...?? This is where I am having trouble understanding the difference; what does find_packages do with said packages after it finds them?

Comment: `pip freeze` lists all Python projects (things on PyPI) that pip has installed in the current environment.  `find_packages()` examines & describes the directory structure of the project you're building; it traverses the current directory looking for folders & subfolders containing `__init__.py` files and returns a list of the form `["package", "package.subpackage", "package.other_subpackage", "package.other_subpackage.subsubpackage", "etc"]`.

Comment: Alright, so does it store that package list somewhere so the next system on which I install the project knows which packages the project needs and can go find them? Or do I have to include the packages in the project so that find_packages can find and install them right from the directory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> use "pip freeze > requirements.txt" command; then "packages='requirements.txt'" in the setup script

Even assuming that by `packages='requirements.txt'` you mean `packages=open('requirements.txt').read().splitlines()`, that is absolutely the wrong thing to do, and I hope that you've simply been misreading whatever sources you've consulted rather than such blatantly wrong information actually being posted somewhere.

The purpose of the `packages` keyword to the `setup()` function is to tell `setuptools` what directories of Python code in your repository are to be included when distributing & installing your project.  For most simple cases, `packages=find_packages()` is all you need.

`requirements.txt`, on the other hand, is supposed to contain a list of other people's projects that your project depends on (and it should really be hand-crafted rather than redirecting `pip freeze` into it like a lobotomized chimp).  The correct `setup()` keyword to pass its contents to is `install_requires`, which is what causes your project's dependencies to also be installed whenever someone installs your project.

Comment: Well I think "lobotomized chimp" is a little harsh but...sure I get what you are saying about the requirements file.  But I still don't understand what find packages is _actually doing_. 

For example, my project uses 5 modules I've downloaded and installed in my python interpreter's "site-packages" directory. I put "find_packages" in my setup.py, then take my project to another system to install it.  I run the setup.py, it gets to find_packages...what happens then? Is it looking though the code to find imported modules? Or must I include the modules in the project somehow?

Comment: The requirements file makes sense to me: "here's a list of modules this install needs, go find them and install them."

I just don't get how "find_packages" can install modules on a system that does not already have the modules on it, like if it's a fresh install of a python interpreter, what packages are there to find?

Comment: @CashBest: I think you may be getting confused by the dual meaning of "package" in this context.  "Package" may refer to either a thing you download & install from PyPI ([PyPUG calls this a "distribution package"](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-distribution-package); I've been calling it a "project") or a folder containing one or more Python files which can be imported in Python with `import folder_name` ([PyPUG calls this an "import package"](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-import-package)).  `find_packages()` and the `packages` keyword deal with the second kind.

Comment: *sigh* I feel like such a dunce right now; this just isn't sinking in for me.
Okay, example: on my dev system I've installed 5 non-standard packages. setup.py has find_packages, it finds those 5 and goes "yup, you're using these." I go to install on a diff system (with fresh python and only standard library installed) and run setup.py. It gets to find_packages, what does it do? How does find_packages on a new system know what find_packages found on the other system?  Right now the only way I can get my project to work elsewhere is to manually install all the modules I use on the new system

Comment: @CashBest: "setup.py has find_packages, it finds those 5" — No.  `find_packages` has absolutely nothing to do with what you've installed.  It's for listing what parts of your project folder are actually part of the Python package you're making and not, say, tests or deployment scripts.  If you're still confused, I suggest you call `find_packages()` in the Python REPL with various project setups and see what it returns.

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a shot; that should help me understand what it's doing at least. That said, by what means can I install required modules on a new system? Do I need to use a requirements file, do I include those libraries in the project or manually install them some way, or is there some means of doing all this automatically like typical executables do?  I know there is py2exe and what not but in using those I seem to be running into the same confusion.  I don't want people to have to write a bunch of python to install modules before they can use my project

Comment: @CashBest: Your project's dependencies need to be declared with the `install_requires` argument to `setup()`.  Whether they're hard-coded there or read from a `requirements.txt` file is up to you.  After that, anyone who installs your project using `pip` will also have those dependencies installed automatically.